# Do tuples have an implicit lexicographical comparison?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

When sorting eg a vector of pairs :

```
vector<pair<int, double>> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

You don't need to specify a sorting criterion to have a sorting based on the lexicographical order of the pairs since, when not elseway specified, a lexicographical comparison applies.

Is a similar behaviour standard for tuples as well ?

In VS2012 this compiles

```
vector<tuple<int, double, char>> tv;
sort(tv.begin(), tv.end());
```

but is it standard mandated to do so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do, see [operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=(std::tuple)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp):

> ```
> operator==
> operator!=
> operator<
> operator<=
> operator>
> operator>=
> ```
>
> lexicographically compares the values in the tuple

Answer (score 6):

According to standard [*20.4.2.7 Relational operators*]: Yes

Overloaded operator for `tuple`:

```
 template<class... TTypes, class... UTypes>
 constexpr bool operator<(const tuple<TTypes...>& t, 
 const tuple<UTypes...>& u);
```

Returns: **The result of a lexicographical comparison between t and u.**

The result is deﬁned as:

```
(bool)(get<0>(t) < get<0>(u)) ||(!(bool)(get<0>(u) < get<0>(t)) && ttail < utail)
```

where `rtail` for some tuple `r` is a tuple containing all but the ﬁrst element of `r`.
 For any two zero-length tuples `e` and `f`, `e < f` returns `false`.

Comment: +1 for copy pasting my answer (that copy pastes the Standard)

Comment: Thanx but I didn't copy your answer. Just the standard. Honestly, I didn't see your answer before I posted mine.

Answer (score 4):

In `20.4.2.7 Relational operators [tuple.rel]`

```
template<class... TTypes, class... UTypes>
bool operator<(const tuple<TTypes...>& t, const tuple<UTypes...>& u);
```

> Returns: The result of a lexicographical comparison between t and u. The result is defined as:

```
(bool)(get<0>(t) < get<0>(u)) || (!(bool)(get<0>(u) < get<0>(t)) && ttail < utail)
```

> where rtail for some tuple r is a tuple containing all but the first element of r. For any two zero-length tuples e and f, e < f returns false.

**So no, they don't have an implicit one, they have an explicit**