# Implementation of lower_bound on vector pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair, lower-bound

I know we need to include some compare function in order to achieve this.

But not able to write for this one.

For example:

Elements of vector=`{(2,4),(4,2),(5,1),(5,3)}`

to find=5

lower_bound() should return 2

**code->**

```
#define pp pair<int,int>

bool cmp(const pp &l,const pp &r) {
    return l.first < r.first;
}

int main() {
   vector<pp> v;
   sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
   int id=(int)(lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), ??) - v.begin());
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `typedef std::pair<int, int> pp;` instead of macro definition.

Comment: But macro definition works too!

Comment: http://ideone.com/M0PZPL

Comment: @user2826957 Yes, but it's not the appropriate way to do it. This is precisely what `typedef`s are for.

Comment: @user2826957 “Macro definition works too!” – No it does not, outside of your trivial example. This has been explained to death on here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 16):

**Pairs** ([just like tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23827203/2567683)) compare **lexicographically** anyway. You **don't need to define any special comparators** for this.

And since you're using `lower_bound` you'll be searching for the first element that does not compare less than the `val` you're searching, so you should use a `min` value as the second pair element. To sum up, **all can be done in "two" lines of code** :

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
auto id = distance(v.begin(), lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(), 
       make_pair(5, numeric_limits<int>::min())) );
```

---

Some Notes :

1. Use `std::distance` to calculate the number of elements between two iterators
2. The return type of `std::distance` is an unsigned type. Unless you need negative indexing (Python like syntax for "count from the end" indexes) it's a good practice to keep your indexes unsigned.

Comment: Can you explain how `numeric_limits<int>::min()` works?

Comment: @KPMG ```numeric_limits<T>``` provides information on numerical types. ```min()``` is a static function returning the smallest number representable by ```T``` (here: ```T``` = ```int```). Likewise, ```numeric_limits<T>::max()``` provides the largest number representable by the type ```T```. These are, for example, very useful when writing functions looking for minima or maxima.
I would guess that ```numeric_limits<int>::max()``` simply sets all the bits of an int to 1.

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't care about the second value of `pp`, just construct a temporary `pp` object with any value as the second element.

```
int id = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), pp(5, 0), cmp) - v.begin();
```

Comment: Better to use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should compare the pairs as per definition of `lower_bound`
So,

```
   typedef pair<int,int> pp;
   //...

   int id=(int)(lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(), 
                pp(5,std::numeric_limits<int>::min())), //Value to compare
                [](const pp& lhs, const pp& rhs)       // Lambda
                {
                    return lhs < rhs ;                //  first argument < second
                }
                 ) - v.begin()
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lower_bound on vector of pairs with custom compare operator .

You need to pass four arguments in that case like this :-

- it1 = iterator position from where to search
- it2 = iterator position till where to search

lower_bound (it1 ,it2 , finding_element, your_comparator )

```
auto myComp = [&](pair<int,string> e1, pair<int,string> e2) {
if(e1.second!=e2.second)
    return e1.second<e2.second;
else
    return e1.first<e2.first;
};
 
void Show_sample_code()
{
    vector<pair<int,string>> data={{1, "sahil"}, {2, "amin"}};
    sort(data.begin(), data.end(), myComp);
    pair<int, string> p={1,"sahil"};
    auto it=lower_bound( data.begin(), data.end(), p, myComp ) ;
    if(it!=data.end())
         cout<<"found at index="<<distance(data.begin(), it)<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"notfound"<<endl;
return;
}
```